# How to edit a particular object by considering the attribute of object instead of the index of the object in Typescript

Tags: typescript

I want to edit a particular object from an object array by considering the `id` instead of considering the `index` of the array. The array as follows

```
data_list = [
    {
        {
            id: "001"
            name: "george",
            age : 20,
            address: "new york"
        },
        {
            id: "002"
            name: "mavan",
            age : 23,
            address: "new york"
        },
        {
            id: "003"
            name: "chris",
            age : 25,
            address: "melborn"
        },
        {
            id: "004"
            name: "jerry",
            age : 26,
            address: "dubai"
        }
    }
]
```

I want to edit follow object by considering `id` as I told in above.

```
{
    id: "003"
    name: "chris",
    age : 25,
    address: "melborn"
},
```

This object should changed as this.

```
{
    id: "003"
    name: "brown",
    age : 29,
    address: "Dilhi"
},
```

Then finally the array should be as follow.

```
data_list = [
        {
            {
                id: "001"
                name: "george",
                age : 20,
                address: "new york"
            },
            {
                id: "002"
                name: "mavan",
                age : 23,
                address: "new york"
            },
            {
                id: "003"
                name: "brown",
                age : 29,
                address: "Dilhi"
            },
            {
                id: "004"
                name: "jerry",
                age : 26,
                address: "dubai"
            }
        }
    ]
```

Then what should I do for this

Comment: Are you sure about that curly brackets line 2 and close to the end? Doesn't look like valid ts for me.